# Is it possible to use dual monitors with World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

As the title says, is it possible to use dual monitors with World of Warcraft?

I don't have a set-up currently but I can see the advantages of using one monitor for WoW and one for a browser open to Wowhead (questing, dungeon runs) or email/RSS/whatever (farming).  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can run two monitors you can use wow in windowed mode and not need to 'alt-tab' or otherwise minimize the warcraft windows.

http://www.google.com/images?q=warcraft+windowed+mode

You can obviously do this without two monitors and have quick access to firefox (or itunes, etrade, etc). There is a performance hit with windowed mode, but it does have dynamic fps (frames per second) to degrade game play video quality to compensate.

Issue with this is that if you are using two video cards, some video cards introduce some issues when you drag windows between video cards or span windows between two different video cards. This isn't an issue with Windows7 any longer.

You also likely want to adjust the setting 'play sound in background' as when you wow window doesn't have focus it won't play sound. So when your surfing wowhead (or stackexchange) you won't notice chats, yourself being attacked, ready checks, etc otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

If you are running a reasonably recent version of windows, the answers is Yes. I run Warcraft in full screen windowed mode and have wowhead open in a browser on my second monitor, along with my vent client.

Answer (score 5):

The "Full screen (Windowed)" display mode (in the WoW display options) is just what you want. It runs the game in windowed mode, but stretches the window to fill the entire screen and hides the title bar/borders/etc. You can switch to another application (say, a web browser on another monitor) and WoW will remain visible.

In contrast, if the game is running in "true" full-screen, switching applications will cause the game to disappear since it is no longer the active window. This is how full-screen apps usually work.

You take a *very* minor performance hit (a few frames per second at most) running in this display mode instead of true full-screen, but it's not noticeable and completely worth it.

Answer (score 1):

My second monitor is my iPad ..

this doesn't really solve the problem you describe, especially since the input methods are so different -> remove fingers from mouse/keyboard, touch the screen etc.

Comment: or a cheap netbook/laptop would acompish the same thing. get a KVM (hardware or software) and can use the same KB and Mouse.

Comment: I've got a four year old laptop that I use currently but in the last week it's started blue screening with memory errors.  A new monitor is a cheaper option, but it would be a good excuse to get an iPad...

Comment: @Xantex: I agree (+1 to comment) .. especially considering things like 'SYNERGY' (see http://synergy-foss.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when running other programs on the other monitor. Videos may rob frames, especially YouTube or other flash-based sites when flash has "Hardware Acceleration" enabled. Windowed mode in itself will take frames away from you, so to get the best performance (e.g. during a raid), switch back to full screen mode.